# How not to lose quality of image with brush

Tags: texture-painting

I'm using texture material on the brush and the quality is way worse than I would like.Original [image]

Painted with a brush
[image]

Comment: Maybe you could provide the "original" as it is (not only the example)

Answer (score 7):

When creating your texture that you are going to paint to, increase this number. (smaller is lower resolution, larger will allow for more detail) It is a good idea to keep powers of 2, such as 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192 Etc.

[image]

In your case, when you already have an image made, you can adjust the size of your image in the tools panel of the **UV/Image Editor**

[image]

Comment: I've already did that, it's 4096x4096

Comment: well, depending on how big your giraffe is, you may need it really big.

Comment: think of it this way, if your texture is 500 pixels by 500 pixels, and you have it repeat 27 times, that is 13,500 pixels by 13,400 pixels (to avoid losing resolution)

Comment: So, since he seems to want an alternative, is there an LOD setup for textures?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, unless you have multiple objects with different textures. Unless this is for the game engine (or merely to speed up render time) I'd say there is no point to use LOD to reduce texture size.